# Inserting python list into SQLite cell

Tags: python, database, sqlite

Here is my insert function

```
def insert(all_in):
with conn:
    c.execute("""INSERT INTO games VALUES (:number, :total_1, :finished_1, :p_1,
                  :total_2, :d_1, :finished_2, :total_3)""",
              {'number': all_in['number'],
               'total_1': all_in['total_1'],
               'finished_1': all_in['finished_1'],
               'p_1': all_in['p_1'],
               'total_2': all_in['total_2'],
               'd_1': all_in['d_1'],
               'finished_2': all_in['finished_2'],
               'total_3': all_in['total_3']})
```

The data I'm trying to pass to the function is

```
result = {'number': '148', 'total_1': '24', 'finished_1': 'Yes',
          'p_1': ['6', 'W', 'X', '1'], 'total_2': '6', 'd_1': ['O', 'P'],
          'finished_2': 'Yes', 'total_3': '30'}
```

When I execute the function

```
insert(all_in=result)
```

I get this error:

```
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter :p_1 - probably unsupported type.
```

I understand I could convert the value of p_1 into a string but I would like to be able to get that value from the database and use it again in python as a list. What is the best way to do this?
PS: All the columns in my table currently have the variable type TEXT of SQLite

Comment: @blhsing I'm not sure, could you enlighten me please?

Comment: Quick summary of the answer to the duplicate question: there's no native support for an array in sqlite3, so you would have to serialize your list and store it as a string instead.

Comment: I am a little new at this, could you walk me through the serializing and deserializing process?

Comment: Please be specific about what confuses you in the answers of the linked question.

Comment: In the answers to the linked question, the goal is to save the list into a column, but here I would like my list to remain in a single cell and be reusable as a list.

Comment: Yes, so after you save the list with a string representation of the list (using `pickle.dumps` or `json.dumps`) into a column/cell, you can retrieve the string from the column/cell and then convert it back into a list (using `pickle.loads` or `json.loads`).

Comment: Thanks @blhsing, I finally was able to understand the problem and solved it using json